Getting error: "could not determine data type of parameter $1' when using Drizzle sql operator with template literals
I have a simple table:
CREATE TABLE items (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, 
  name VARCHAR (50) UNIQUE NOT NULL, 
  price decimal NOT NULL
);


INSERT INTO items (name, price)
VALUES 
  ('sprocket1-2a', 50.0),
  ('bolt-2x', 39.10),
  ('nut2-7a', 88.50);

Using Drizzle, I'm trying to execute a raw SQL query like
db.execute(
  sql`SELECT * FROM items WHERE name ILIKE '%${search}%'`,
),

but I'm getting the error
Error: could not determine data type of parameter $1

I know that I can do
${sql.raw(search)}

to get around this but I don't want to do that as 'search' will be coming from users. How can I safely take in user input here?

I don't use Drizzle, but I suspect you need '%'||${search}||%'.

@AdrianKlaver you're missing an apostrophe and I did try: '%' || ${search} || '%' which did work but I guess now I'm wondering if this is safe or is it just another way of doing sql.raw()

Yes as it is the search parameter that will be mapped to a placeholder per sql operator. It would be easy enough to test, try some unsafe input.

You should create something like this:
const preparedSearch = `%${search}%`;
db.execute(
  sql`SELECT * FROM items WHERE name ILIKE ${preparedSearch}`,
);


